# Whether Google Captcha is required in Google signin?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Hi i am using web application with google signin.
For google signin, is it required to include google recaptcha? 
Is it neccessary for security purpose when sigin the application using google account or not?

Comment: google sign in? You mean OAuth?

Comment: No, it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google sign in you don't need recaptcha. Google will automatically do the security procedure.